# Personalisation String in Inline If statement

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Does Inline If not work for personalisation strings?

I have the following code:

```
http://www.website.com?utm_source=sfmc&utm_medium=%%=IIF(NOT EMPTY(%%Variable1%%), %%Variable1%%, "")=%%
```

Does not seem to work,
The output comes out as:

```
http://www.website.com?utm_source=sfmc&utm_medium=%%=IIF(NOT EMPTY(email), email, "")=%%
```

But my expected output would be:

```
http://www.website.com?utm_source=sfmc&utm_medium=email
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont know if you want to display the link or if it should be inside a  but usually i would go for something with concat or redirect (depending on the use case)

```
%%=Concat('http://www.website.com?utm_source=sfmc&utm_medium=',IIF(NOT EMPTY(Variable1), Variable1, ""))=%%
```

or

```
%%=RedirectTo(Concat('http://www.website.com?utm_source=sfmc&utm_medium=',IIF(NOT EMPTY(Variable1), Variable1, "")))=%%
```

This only works with personalization strings like `emailaddr` if you need to get variables or some transformation you need to set the variables first, and it then would become something like:

```
%%=RedirectTo(Concat('http://www.website.com?utm_source=sfmc&utm_medium=',IIF(NOT EMPTY(@variable1), @variable1, "")))=%%
```

**Ressource:**

- [**Personalization Strings**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_available_personalization_strings.htm&type=5)

Comment: That's what I wanted to clarify, thanks so much Johannes!